# Bootstrap create additional <a> tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code:

```
<div class="footer">
<div class="footer-inner">
     2013 &copy; {$config.system.site_name} - <a href="">правила</a> - <a href="">уведомление о рисках</a>.
</div>
<div class="footer-tools">
<span class="go-top">
<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
```

It shows me this in the DOM inspector (in all browsers):

[image]

When I turn off the bootstrap.min.css, the mystical  tag disappeared! Why is that?

WOW. I turned off all .css files and .js files, but the "a" tag did not disappear! How can that be?

Comment: Try to give some class to your anchor and some properties, maybe something is messed up in `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: put your text inside a `<p></p>` tag, and try again

Comment: <p></p> not work, just add one more <a></a>

Comment: Looks like there's a footer-inner:before that's wrecking havoc there. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. Just close and open browsers, and all turn back to normal, the most insane glitch i ever saw.

Comment: Probably a cache issue. Remember to clear that often with each web browser you use for testing.